# Can I alias a subcommand? (shortening the output of `docker ps`)

Tags: docker, zsh

The `docker` command has a `ps` sub-command that emits very long lines:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        NAMES
6e8ec8a16da4        waisbrot/wait:latest              "/wait"                  4 minutes ago       Exited (0) 4 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 wait-for-janus-test
9dbf0739561f        whoop/downsampler:master          "./run.bash"             4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                0.0.0.0:32855->4369/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32854->9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32853->9101/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32852->9102/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32851->9103/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32850->9104/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32849->9105/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32848->9106/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32847->9107/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32846->9108/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32845->9109/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32844->9110/tcp   metrics-downsampler-test
6cf56623bb48        whoop/janus:master                "./start.bash"           4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                0.0.0.0:32843->80/tcp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        janus-test
882b50303d54        whoop/recalculator:master         "./run.bash"             4 minutes ago       Exited (1) 4 minutes ago                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 internum-test
```

It can be instructed to output only specific columns:

```
docker ps --format "table {{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}\t{{.Status}}"
```

I'd like to be able to say `docker ps` and get the `--format "table..."` argument added on for me. Is there a nice way to do this?

I know I could say

```
alias dp='docker ps --format ...'
```

but I'd prefer to keep the sub-command.

I'm using zsh as my shell.

Comment: In general, shell aliases have very minimal functionality -- prefix substitution, no room for conditional logic. If you want to do anything fancy at all, a function is pretty much always better.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can wrap `docker` in a function that checks for the specific subcommand and passes everything else through. (The below will actually work with not just zsh, but any POSIX-compliant shell -- a category to which zsh doesn't quite belong).

```
docker() {
  case $1 in
    ps)
      shift
      command docker ps --format 'table {{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}\t{{.Status}}' "$@"
      ;;
    *)
      command docker "$@";;
  esac
}
```

---

If you wanted a more generic wrapper function (that doesn't need to know about your specific desired `ps` logic), that could be done as follows (note that this version is *not* compatible with baseline POSIX sh due to its use of `local`; however, this is an extension implemented even by `ash` and its derivatives):

```
docker() {
  local cmd=$1; shift
  if command -v "docker_$cmd" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
    "docker_$cmd" "$@"
  else
    command docker "$cmd" "$@"
  fi
}
```

...after which any subcommand can have its own functions defined, without the wrapper needing to be modified to know about them (you could also create a script in the PATH named `docker_ps`, or provide the command in any other manner you choose):

```
docker_ps() {
  command docker ps --format 'table {{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}\t{{.Status}}' "$@"
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about using `command` to allow the function and the binary to coexist. That second version is a neat way of thinking about the problem, too. Thanks!

Comment: I can't claim credit for the idea -- look at how `git foo` runs `git-foo`; I used underscores instead here to allow standards-compliant function names to be used (it's possible to define functions with dashes in their names in both bash and zsh, but not POSIX sh).

Answer (score 4):

### Using Docker Config

Since this is fundamentally a docker questions, not a bash question, you don't even need an alias.  Docker CLI allows you to customize these commands in your own config file! From this great tip from [Container 42](https://container42.com/2016/03/27/docker-quicktip-7-psformat/):

1. Create or find your docker config file (if you've ever used [`docker login`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) it should already be created.

   ```
   ~/.docker/config.json
   ```
2. Then add the default formatting for docker to use every time it runs the `ps` command as a top level property in the config:

   ```json
   {
       "psFormat": "table {{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}\t{{.Status}}",
   }
   ```
3. Then just run [`docker ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) like normal:

   [image: docker ps]

#### PS Format

Docker uses [go templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) and has a [list of the valid placeholders](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#formatting):

| Command | Description |
| --- | --- |
| **`.ID`** | Container ID |
| **`.Image`** | Image ID |
| **`.Command`** | Quoted command |
| **`.CreatedAt`** | Time when the container was created. |
| **`.RunningFor`** | Elapsed time since the container was started. |
| **`.Ports`** | Exposed ports. |
| **`.Status`** | Container status. |
| **`.Size`** | Container disk size. |
| **`.Names`** | Container names. |
| **`.Labels`** | All labels assigned to the container. |
| **`.Label`** | Value of a specific label for this container. |
| **`.Mounts`** | Names of the volumes mounted in this container. |
| **`.Networks`** | Names of the networks attached to this container. |

#### Alternative Solutions / Threads

- Github Issues

  - [Default "docker ps" output is too wide](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7477)
  - [docker ps output is so long it's unreadable](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/279)
- Third Party Commands

  - [**ctop**](https://github.com/bcicen/ctop) - Top-like interface for container metrics
  - [**docker-pretty-ps**](https://github.com/politeauthority/docker-pretty-ps) - beautiful, colored, long output log
  - [**dockerps**](https://github.com/sadorlovsky/dockerps) - A better docker ps

Answer (score 2):

**You can alias subcommands.**  With aliasing, you still get the nice zsh completions as if you were typing the full command.  That's why I prefer them over functions.

The equivalent of your alias is:

```sh
alias dp='docker ps --format "table {{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}'\t{{.Status}}"
```

But the full commands seem to now be recommended, and `ls` has replaced `ps`, which makes your alias now:

```sh
alias dp='docker container ls --format "table {{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}'\t{{.Status}}"
```

It's nice to have docker aliases for everything.  For this, I've been working on a set of [comprehensive aliases](https://github.com/MicahElliott/scad), which would have your alias as something like:

```sh
alias ddcls='docker container ls --format "table {{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}\t{{.Status}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to disable only `docker login` command (some folks used that command on our CI-runner breaking a generic config file for docker).
So, I added to my `.bashrc`:

```
_docker() {
  if [ "$1" = "login" ]; then
    echo "login is disabled, to login please update a config file manually!"
    return
  fi
  
  /usr/bin/docker "$@"
}

alias docker="_docker"
```