# How to write an alias for "two" words

Tags: bash

The standard usage of an alias is to write a shortcut for an expanded command, for example: `alias ls='ls --color'`.

I want to know if it's possible to have "parameters" in the left side, so that it works the other way around. Using the above example, I'm interesting in knowing if `alias ls --color='ls'`is possible, that is, when someone types `ls --color`, the simple `ls` is run.

Forget about whether or not that's useful or make sense, I just want to know if it's possible, or if there is any workaround to achieve the same goal.

Comment: There is no way of doing this with aliases. Instead you can define a bash function `ls` that drops the `--color` option and calls the `ls` *executable* with the remaining arguments.

Comment: If your real goal is to intercept something like, say, `git commit`, while leaving other `git` subcommands unmodified, we already have Q&A entries in the knowledgebase for that.

Comment: ...so, if I'm correctly reading the question, what you're *really* trying to do is presumably something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748747/can-i-alias-a-subcommand-shortening-the-output-of-docker-ps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The existing answer doesn't correctly handle commands with spaces -- and indeed cannot: Condensing an array into a string is inherently buggy.

This version works with the list of arguments *as an array*, and thus avoids this loss of information:

```
ls() {
  local -a args=( )
  for arg; do
    [[ $arg = --color ]] || args+=( "$arg" )
  done
  command ls "${args[@]}"
}
```

Alternately, if your real goal is to alias a subcommand (and you might want to process more subcommands in the future), consider a `case` structure, as the following:

```
ls() {
  local subcommand

  if (( "$#" == 0 )); then command ls; return; fi    

  subcommand=$1; shift
  case $subcommand in
    --color)  command ls "$@" ;;
    *)        command ls "$subcommand" "$@" ;;
  esac
}
```

---

Some tests, to distinguish correctness between this answer and the preexisting one:

```
tempdir=/tmp/ls-alias-test
mkdir -p "$dir"/'hello world' "$dir"/my--color--test

# with the alternate answer, this fails because it tries to run:
#   ls /tmp/ls-alias-test/hello world
# (without the quotes preserved)
ls --color "$dir/hello world"

# with the alternate answer, this fails because it tries to run:
#   ls /tmp/ls-alias-test/my--test
ls --color "$dir/my--color--test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function after unalias ls:

```
unalias ls
ls () { p=$@; p=${p//--color/}; /bin/ls $p ;}
```

Comment: but how do I use this? I mean, if I just type it in the terminal, I get an unexpected token error on the first `(`. If I paste that into a file, and the in `.bashrc` I do source that file, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, i missed one word.

Comment: @IporSircer It's better to simply put a space between the function name and the `()` than to use the non-standard keyword `function`. `ls () { ...; }` will work fine.

Comment: @chepner: tried. Also drops a syntax error. It may be a bash bug. (4.4.0)

Comment: Is the alias still defined when you try to define the function? Having an alias *and* a function with the same name is something the `function` keyword allows you to do, but it's probably a bad idea. You'd be stuck having to do things like `\ls` to call the function since `ls` by itself would expand to the alias.

Comment: @chepner: you're right! I've forgot the default aliases of bash. (i'm using mksh primary)

Comment: Using a function is the right thing, but this particular implementation is very buggy -- try to pass it multi-word arguments

Comment: For instance, `ls 'directory with spaces'` will behave badly.

Comment: ...or, for another example of where this goes wrong: `mkdir ./my--color--wheel; touch my--color--wheel/foo.txt; ls --color ./my--color--wheel`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: it's just a proof of concept. He can adjust this skeleton if he experienced error with exotic names.

Comment: @IporSircer, if what it proves is an approach that's inherently broken and cannot be made to work robustly, then it proves nothing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: feel free to correct it.

Comment: Yes, I'm adding my own answer for that reason. By "cannot be made to work robustly", I'm attempting to indicate that the answer given here (coalescing argv to a string and performing pattern-matching on that string) is uncorrectable.

Comment: @IporSircer, ...btw, `ls` is not actually a default alias in bash, though some distros often add it in their own init scripts.