# Make $ docker compose a command for docker-compose

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to have `docker compose` run `docker-compose` in a bash alias?

I know `docker` is a command of it's own so I don't think you can, I thought I would ask since it drive's me nuts making aliases when I type `docker` so much.

i already have `alias dco=docker-compose` but you know, a brother is looking for a better way. :)

Comment: Why not make your own docker command that calls the real docker or docker-compose based on the args?

Comment: Alias are just straight-up text replacement; `alias dco='docker compose'` would work.

Comment: Or are you looking for a way to parameterize the alias, so that one alias covers multiple subcommands? For that, you need to use a function: something like `d () { if [[ $1 = com* ]]; then docker compose "${@:2}"; elif ... fi; }`, which would let you run `d co` to run `docker compose`.

Comment: See similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748747/can-i-alias-a-subcommand-shortening-the-output-of-docker-ps

Comment: @chepner and if we want to bash autocomplete work with `dco` like with `docker-compose`, we can add little workaround. First step, find complete config string with `complete | grep docker-compose`. Second, change found string from `complete -F _docker_compose docker-compose` to `complete -F _docker_compose dco` and save it to the file `~/.bash_completion`. Now I got any subcommand expand with <Tab> :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a `function` instead:

```
docker() {
  if [ "$1" = "compose" ]
  then
    shift
    docker-compose "$@"
  else
    command docker "$@"
  fi
}
```

Here the `command` prevents the `docker` function from calling itself again.

See also: [Can I alias a subcommand? (shortening the output of `docker ps`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748747/can-i-alias-a-subcommand-shortening-the-output-of-docker-ps)
as commented by @zlemini